# Why does std::unique_lock have a default constructor?

Tags: c++, std

I was watching [this talk](https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g) by Louis Brandy, when a fellow viewer asked this obvious question:

> **Why does std::unique_lock have a default constructor?**

And now I have to know.

Comment: Sometimes it's convenient to be able to create an object before assign a value to it. Remember that you can move assign to a `std::unique_lock`. Since the type already supports move semantics and offers a well-defined moved-from state, it's trivial and harmless to also provide a default constructor that provides the same state.

Comment: How would you have a std::vector of std::unique_lock without a default constructor?

Comment: @UKMonkey That's an interesting point, but strictly speaking a type doesn't need a default constructor to be compatible with `std::vector`.

Comment: It does need to be copyable or default-constructible to use `resize` though, and `unique_lock` isn't copyable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unique_lock` is movable. It has a moved-from state that is basically "empty", not associated with any mutex. This state can also be reached by calling `release()`.

Given that this state exists, and the benefits of having a default-constructor (such as being able to create arbitrarily-sized dynamic arrays), it's a good idea to add the default constructor that creates the same state.

Comment: Marking as accepted. I guess the follow-up question is "what can you actually *do* with a default constructed unique_lock", because an arbitrarily-sized dynamic array of useless objects is, by the transitive property, surely just a useless object?

Comment: @deworde You can individually replace the elements of the array with useful objects.